# Execute a method by pressing Keyboard modifiers in Excel VSTO Workbook project

Tags: c#-3.0, vsto

I have a workbook project(VSTO 2007). What I want to do is that I want to execute some method by pressing CTRL+R.

What I have done is  the below

```
private void InternalStartup()
 {
   this.btnProcessTable.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnProcessTable_Click);

   Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.OnKey("^r", "test");
 }
```

And the test method is

```
private void test()
{
            MessageBox.Show("Just a test");
}
```

Next when I ran the application and press CTRL + R , I encounter the below message

**Cannot run the macro test. The macro maynot be available in this workbook or all macro's may be disable**

I check that all the macros are enable and the funciton (test) is in the same workbook.

Any idea of how to fix the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Hi priyanka.sarkar_2, i have almost same problem with your's.The only difference is that i do not have error but nothing happen when i press a key on my workbook.Let me know please, if you could find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you need to declare your function as **public**. Having a **private** function will hide it from the overlying system somehow.

```
public void test()
{
            MessageBox.Show("Just a test");
}
```

Comment: I already tried with that.. and more over both are in the same class.. So the access modifier is not an issue

Comment: Well, then I can't help you out. Sorry to have put your hopes up, with an answer, you already tried.